# <Identifier> Expected- Having major difficulty, New to coding

Tags: java

```
class Maths{
    // Attributes of maths
    private int num1;
    private int num2;

//Constructor
public Maths ***- This is where the error is*** 
{
    add = a;
    subtract = s;
    multiply = m;
    divide = d;

}

//Get me some Accessors

public String getAdd() 
{
return add;
}

public string getSubtract()
{
    return subtract;
}

public String getMultiply()
{
    return multiply;
}

public String getDivide()
{
    return divide;
}

}
}
```

Alright so I'm new to programming, Absolutely newborn. I'm really not sure what to do for this. I need to *"Write a class called Maths.  It has 2 attributes called num1 and num2. It has a constructor.  It will have methods called Add(), subtract(), multiply() and divide().(Hint: integer division use modulus operator). Most of these methods return the result.
Write all the getters and setters and a toString() method."*

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html. Don't you have a book where you can learn the syntax? Don't you have google to find examples of constructors? Don't you think add and a should be declared variables for this code to makse sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Maths constructor you have forgotten  parenthesis `()`

Do like this

```
public Maths() 
{
    add = a;
    subtract = s;
    multiply = m;
    divide = d;

}
```

Comment: Thanks alot, knew it was a rookie mistake.

Comment: What is `a`/`add`, `s`/`substract`, `m`/`multiply` and `d`/`divide`? This will be the next problem...

Answer (score 0):

constructor has the same name as class and parenthesis. 
this is what you need to put there.

```
 public Maths()
    {
     add = a;
    subtract = s;
    multiply = m;
    divide = d;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, It's exactly as you and Jquery said, Although I'm getting more errors with the variable add.. Thanks anyway guys!

Comment: @user3260354 you need to declare variables before you use it.
as i can see add , subtract etc don't have declarations moreover if this constructor is a default constructor the values you are assigning to add,subtract etc as a,s respectively they are also not declared.

Comment: _ "Write a class called Maths. It has 2 attributes called num1 and num2. It has a constructor. It will have methods called Add(), subtract(), multiply() and divide().(Hint: integer division use modulus operator). Most of these methods return the result. Write all the getters and setters and a toString() method." _ 
I'm attempting to do this. But as you can see, Having difficulty

Comment: I think googling would help you even more.@Seph
Ex. http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110416125051AAxA3r9